# Naming a graph with list name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think I am pretty far off here but just trying to understand the essentials. I want to make a combined graph each by the grouping name. However I am having troubling understanding the set_names function. When I used the code belows it name each graph "carat", but I though I set names to the clarity column.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(gridExtra)


carat_histogram <- function(df) {
   label= names({{df}})
     
    ggplot(df, aes(x = carat)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1)+
      labs(title = label)
     }

by_clarity <- diamonds |> 
  group_nest(clarity)

by_clarity_named <- set_names(by_clarity$data, nm = by_clarity$clarity)

names(by_clarity_named)

by_clarity_named<-map(by_clarity_named, carat_histogram)


do.call(grid.arrange,by_clarity_named)
```

Do you have any suggestions?

I have tried

```
by_clarity_named <- set_names(by_clarity, nm = by_clarity$clarity)

#Error in `set_names()`: ! The size of `nm` (8) must be compatible with the size of `x` (2).
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

When mapping over a list, you cannot get the current element's name. If you want to iterate over names and values, instead use the function `imap` rather than `map`. And change your function so it accepts a label. For example

```
carat_histogram <- function(df, label) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = carat)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1)+
    labs(title = label)
}

by_clarity <- diamonds |> 
  group_nest(clarity)
by_clarity_named <- set_names(by_clarity$data, nm = by_clarity$clarity)
by_clarity_named <- imap(by_clarity_named, carat_histogram)
do.call(grid.arrange, by_clarity_named)
```

This will produce
[image]

If you were to add `print(label)` to your original function, you'd see that `names({{df}})` was just returning all the names of the columns in the data.frame. The names from the named list are not available at that time.

Comment: Thank you very much!  To clarify you set label as a second arguement in the function but where in the imap function is that second arguement stated?

Comment: Check the documentation for `?imap`. it expects a function that takes two parameters.